# How to derive $ f(\beta) =\| y-X \beta \|^2 + \lambda\| \beta\|^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given  $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$,  $X \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, find the value of $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^n$, that minimizes $ f(\beta) =\| y-X \beta \|^2 +  \lambda\| \beta\|^2$.

My problem is that I have no idea how to derive $f$, like you see in my attempt.

Derive the first part:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \| y-X \beta \|^2 = 2 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \| y-X \beta \| =  2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\| y-X \beta \|} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \sum_{i=0}^{n} (y_i-X \beta)^2 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2\| y-X \beta \|} \cdot 2 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n} {y_i-X \beta} \cdot X  = \frac{1}{\| y-X \beta \|} \cdot 2 \cdot (y-X \beta) \cdot X$$

And the second part:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \lambda\| \beta\|^2 = 2\lambda \cdot \| \beta\| \cdot \frac{\beta}{\| \beta\|} = 2\lambda \cdot \beta$$

Now I have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \| y-X \beta \|^2 +  \lambda\| \beta\|^2 
 = \frac{1}{\| y-X \beta \|} \cdot 2 \cdot (y-X \beta) \cdot X + 2\lambda \cdot \beta$$

But this can' be right if i can trust my tummy, can you show me the way to go?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/69205/119261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's focus on differentiating the first term. You have

$$\|y-X\beta\|^2 = \sum_i \left(y_i - \sum_j X_{ij}\beta_j\right)^2.$$

Differentiating with respect to $\beta_k$ gives you

$$-2\sum_i \left(y_i - \sum_{j} X_{ij}\beta_j\right)X_{ik} = -2\left(y-X\beta\right)^\top X_{\cdot k}$$

where $X_{\cdot k}$ denotes the $k$th column of $X$. Applying this to every $k$, you can write the vector equation

$$\nabla_\beta \|y-X\beta\|^2 = -2\left(y-X\beta\right)^\top X.$$

For the entire function $f$, you have

$$\nabla_\beta f\left(\beta\right) = -2\left(y-X\beta\right)^\top X + 2\lambda\beta^\top.$$

So, yes, the chain rule applies, but you need to be a bit careful since the product in this case is a matrix-vector product. Writing $\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}$ is misleading because you are taking the gradient, not just a partial derivative.

Comment: Could you explain where the transposed   $(y-X \beta)^T$ >why not $y-X \beta)$< comes from?

Comment: If you write $(y-X\beta)$, then your dimensions won't match for matrix-vector multiplication. In general, $\sum_i a_i B_{ik} = a^\top B_{\cdot k}$ for any vector $a$ and matrix $B$ of suitable size.